# How to get a list of file names in different lines

Tags: unix, ls

I want to get a list of all the files in a directory, like with `ls`, so that each filename will be on a seperate line, without the extra details supplied by `ls -l`. I looked at `ls --help` and didn't find a solution. I tried doing

```
ls -l | cut --fields=9 -d" "
```

but `ls` doesn't use a fixed number of spaces between columns. Any idea on how to do this, preferably in one line?

Answer (score 293, accepted):

`ls -1`

That is a number, not small `L`.

Comment: i see this in the documentation:

cross -x, commas -m, horizontal -x, long -l, single-column -1, verbose -l, vertical -C

i'm not sure how they came up with some of these.

Answer (score 26):

`ls -1`. From the help:

> -1                         list one file per line

Works on cygwin and FreeBSD, so it's probably not too GNU-specific.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu as well. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

solution without pipe-ing :-)

```
 ls --format single-column
```

Note that the long options are only supported on the [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Common-options.html#Common-options) where [BSD ls](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ls) only supports the short arguments `-1`

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps:

```
ls | awk '{print $NF}'
```

Comment: note: a file name with spaces such as "apples and pears.jpg" will turn into "pears.jpg"

Answer (score 5):

`ls | cat`
...
or possibly, `ls -1`

Comment: Please do avoid the useless use of cat :)

Comment: `cat` is not useless in this instance. It formats the output of `ls` in one column as OP asks for.

Answer (score 3):

Use sed command to list single columns

```
ls -l | sed 's/\(^[^0-9].\*[0-9]\*:[0-9]\*\) \(.*\)/\2/'
```

Comment: `ls -l` produces the same output as your whole answer. Not sure what `sed` is adding here...

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$ ls | xargs -n num
```

Here `num` is number of columns you want to list in.

Answer (score 1):

first you can use this. it will display the one file per line.

ls -l | sed 's/(.* )(.*)$/\2/'

or else you can use thus

find . -maxdepth 1 | sed 's/.///'

both the things are the same.

Comment: I get the error `sed: -e expression #1, char 16: invalid reference \2 on \`s' command's RHS`

Answer (score 0):

This is also working: **echo -e "\n$(ls)"**

Answer (score -1):

This will also do

```
ls -l | awk '{print $NF}'
```

Comment: How is this practically any different from Eelvex's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5155730/369450)?